# Jist/swans debug problem

Tags: java, eclipse, wireless, simulator, adhoc

I am working on [**JiST/SWANS**](http://jist.ece.cornell.edu/), Java-based discrete event simulator, in Eclipse.

Moreover, in Vanet.info (http://vanet.info/node/14) extensions and improvements for JiST/SWANS have been developed.

I used all the instructions(**http://vanet.info/node/119**) in Vanet info to prepare my simulation environment.

There is no error after build, however I cant perform the "debug". When I debug build.xml with antbuild to run aodvsim, breakpoints on aodvsim.java have no effect.

Help me to debug this project ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "Debug As..."/"Ant Build", you can only debug the Ant script itself, not the Java programs it may execute.

In order to do this, AFAIK, you need to create a debug configuration in Eclipse, with the same JVM parameters (classpath, command line etc.) as specified in the Ant target you want to work with. That should be easy with the target "run.jist.aodvsim" target, but it might be more difficult with other tasks.

BTW, i found your post interesting after looking for JiST/SWANS questions on StackOverflow... sorry for the 5 months delay!

Best regards

Enrico